# Window Batch File - Can't get filename in specified folder

Tags: batch-file

I solving this for almost whole day. Can anyone tell me why this code is not listing out the filename?I guess i get error on below code due to I run it and I didn't see anything happen. FYI I am using Window 7.

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\3535-2D\*.ini"')
echo %%a
pause
```

Any changes I need to made?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\310152922\Desktop\Mohit_Task\AutomatedScript\3535-2D\*.ini"') do echo %%a
pause
```

You forgot the `do` clause in the for command. Also, the `/f` switch is used to read the file or process the string, not to enumerate files.

Comment: Woah..thanks for the fast solving MC ND! Thank you very much. Btw, this is getting the full path include the folder path. If there any way to get only the filename EG. Thisfile.ini ?

Comment: @user2709555, use `echo %%~nxa`, that is, the name and extension of the file referenced in `%%a`. See `for /?` for a complete reference of modifiers